# Apache Flink Streaming files from directory

Tags: apache-flink

I want to load a bunch of csv files into Apache Flink in a given order, e.g. as determined by a naming scheme in the file names, which could contain some time stamp information.

In Apache Spark I can stream files to a data set as soon as they are moved to a specific directory (e.g. /data/staging) with an atomic file move as follows

```
Dataset<Row> fileStreamDf = spark.readStream()
            .option("header", true)
            .schema(schema)
            .csv("/data/staging")
```

I would then move the files one by one in the given order, e.g. with a bash script, to that staging directory.

How can I achieve the same thing with Apache Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly the same use case, but we had to do something similar in a streaming job (the files are `HDF5` not `CSV`). So I wrote a `RichSourceFunction` that knows how to iterate over the files in the proper order, and emits the file paths (these are in S3) as String records. Then a downstream `FlatMapFunction` parses the file and emits the actual rows.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I can see how it works. Our setup is actually quite similar, we have csv (and ev. hdf5) on S3. Probably using Kafka as a source may be a possible solution. The real time data comes in from a Kafka channel already.

Comment: Hi Daniel - if the data is in Kafka then yes, sourcing from that (versus going through S3) would make sense. PS - if my answer was helpful, please accept :)

Comment: Thanks was helpful. I think this may be a feature that should be part of the basic Flink stack as it is so common in a testing setup and when you have to merge historical and real time data